# Can Nymphs use shields?

Tags: mazes-and-minotaurs

Can Nymphs use shields in Mazes & Minotaurs?

For other classes, it's explicitly states which items cannot be used. For Nymphs it only says:

> "Nymphs may never wear any kind of armor, as it obviously detracts from their natural (and even supernatural) grace."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

given the intent of that rule (detracts from natural grace) it would suggest that the answer is no.

Wearing armour would obviously hide a nymph's natural charms, and I would consider a nymph with hulking great shield to be similarly grace-less.

Comment: Mind you, some of the "armour" in fantasy art doesn't hide much (read: any) of the charms of portrayed females.  :)

Comment: @JUST MY correct OPINION: That is TRUE.

Comment: well... I always figured it wasn't about protecting the wearer, more about distracting the attacker :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on the specific game system, but if the intent is "not to hide th nymph's natural charms" I'd allow a buckler-style shield (assuming the rules allow this kind of distinction) - i.e. anything "small" is ok in my book.

Think a more or less naked female version of Captain America and let me know if this "hides the charms" or not... ;)

Comment: I don't think 'grace' means 'physical figure' here :) The shield's not in the way by hiding her boobs behind it, its to get in the way of the overall sensuous movement and look. Give a ballerina a buckler and see if she still dances as well - that's where I was coming from.